# Collapse the list of sets based on common element

Tags: scala, functional-programming, set

I have something that looks like an easy enough problem that I wanted to solve functionally using Scala but cannot figure it out.
I am learning Scala and want to make sure that its done using functional programming principles. Below piece of code (which doesnt even work...) is all I managed and
it still has a mutable variable...
Any help is appreciated.

Basically I have a list of sets and I want to join all the sets that has common elements.
And apply that recursively, i.e. keep joining the sets in the list until they are only disjointed ones left.

So for input 
`List(Set(1,2,3), Set(4,1,5), Set(6,2,7), Set(8,9))` I want to get `List(Set(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), Set(8,9))`.

My code below - again it doesnt fully work.

```
    def mergeSets(sets: List[Set[Int]]): List[Set[Int]] = {
        @tailrec
        def go(list: List[Set[Int]], result: List[Set[Int]]): List[Set[Int]] = list match {
          case Nil => result
          case h :: t => {
            var tmpResult = result
            tmpResult = list.filter(_.intersect(h).nonEmpty).map(_ ++ h) ::: result
            tmpResult = list.filter(_.intersect(h).isEmpty) ::: tmpResult
            go(t, tmpResult.toSet.toList)
          }
        }
        go(sets, List())
      }
```

Comment: Replace Nil with empty list:  List()  this is classical mistake. Try simple logic with out complex type like List[Set[Int]]. Did you try to do this in scala worksheet???

Comment: @PavelOliynyk List() instead of Nil is a good tip but doesnt change the result. I have worked out the simple cases as I can join single sets, just struggling to put it all together to work on seq of them (e.g. List[Set[Int]])

Comment: Feel free to show sample of code which are not working as long as you progressing. Thats the purpose of this forum. Just update original story.

Comment: @PavelOliynyk not sure what you mean, I have put the code which is not fully working above. I could include some ScalaTest cases also.

Comment: Check api first: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/Set.html There is a very nice method at the top of the list you could use.

Comment: make sure you use scala worksheet. this will save your time!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the "one line" solution that combines higher order functions to get the desired result:

```
val l = val l = List(Set(1,2,3), Set(4,1,5), Set(6,2,7), Set(8,9))
(for (el <- l) yield 
     l.foldLeft(el)((s, x) =>
            if (s.intersect(x).size > 0) s.union(x) else s)
).toSet
```

The main ideas is iterate over every set and yield the union of all the appropriate sets. The only trick here is using of `toSet` in order to remove duplicates.

Comment: I like this solution, seems clever. Was looking for something that uses foldLeft or reduceLeft as I had the feeling you can do it this way. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a tuple return type instead of a List since you want the position to have meaning. The strategy I used below is to fold over each set, and for each one, if there's another set that has any common elements, add to the first tuple position, otherwise add to the second.

```
def mergeSets(sets: Set[Int]*): (Set[Int], Set[Int]) = {
  sets.foldLeft((Set.empty[Int], Set.empty[Int])) { case ((c, d), n) =>
    if (sets.exists(s => n.exists(s.contains) && s != n))
      (c ++ n, d)
    else
      (c, d ++ n)
  }
}

val (common, disjointed) = mergeSets(Set(1,2,3), Set(4,1,5), Set(6,2,7), Set(8,9))

println(common)
// Set(5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 4)


println(disjointed)
// Set(8, 9)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Its not fully producing the results I expected as there might be multiple common or disjointed sets but it probably could be modified to work that way.